# How to store more than 5 fields for a test step?

Tags: opentap-proj

The OpenTap database schema diagram is shown here:

https://doc.opentap.io/Developer%20Guide/Result%20Listener/#opentap-sql-database

The Result table has 5 fields (from Dim0 to Dim4) meant for storing result data for each test step.

My question is:

**What is the best way to store an arbitrary amount of fields (more than 5) for a particular test step?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 is only the default number. If results have more dimensions, the existing database plugins (PostgreSQL and SQLite) will dynamically add more columns, so all that is needed is to use the proper Results.Publish method from a Test Step:

https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap/-/tree/master/sdk/Examples/PluginDevelopment/TestSteps/PublishResults